# Need to Delete data correctly in column F if met empty cells on G

Tags: vba, excel, range

My code is limited to work fine only with first empty cell found, the problem starts is that if finds the next two or more empty cells because it loops a bit (I can handle with that), but if it finds empty cells and next finds cells with data again, it totally fails.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

firstRow = 7
lastrow = Sheets("Datos del Proyecto").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
i = firstRow
Do Until i > lastrow
    If Sheets("Datos del Proyecto").Range("G" & i).Value Like "" Then
        Sheets("Datos del Proyecto").Range("F" & i).ClearContents
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: is this code of `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` inside "Datos del Proyecto" sheet ?

Comment: Hi, yes, the code is inside the sheet objects, it works OK with first criteria, when there is data in row "TRABAJADOR 5" it only loops, so I need to press Esc twice, then it shows that the problem is in the line "End If".

Comment: try the code below and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the code is placed inside "Datos del Proyecto" sheet, in `Worksheet_Change` event, there is no need to reference it in the code all the time, as it is the default sheet.

Using `Application.EnableEvents = False` will prevent the code to exit and re-enter the `Sub` as you `ClearContents` each iteration inside the `For` loop.

### Code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

' disable worksheet events >> will prevent the endless loop you got
Application.EnableEvents = False

' find last row in Column F
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

' loop through all rows from row 7 until last row
For i = 7 To LastRow
    If IsEmpty(Range("G" & i)) Or Range("G" & i).Value = "" Then
        Range("F" & i).ClearContents
    End If
Next i

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

You can ass an option to your `Sub` , to make it run only if the change occurred in certain `Range` by adding these 3 lines in the beginning of the code:

```
Dim WatchRange     As Range

' check only if cells changed are in Column G
Set WatchRange = Columns("G:G")  
If Not Intersect(Target, WatchRange) Is Nothing Then
```

Comment: You just give me the idea first to add this in my first code @Shai :

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.EnableEvents = True

And it worked! For sure I tasted your code and it worked!, I couldn't run your second suggested option to limitate changes in only certain Range.

I compare both ones codes that work and I didn't notice difference on the Loop (the more far away row on F edited, more loop) or any time to calculations, their reactions are almost instantaneous.

Answer (score 0):

@Shai_Rado answer:

```
'Option Explicit <-- I needed to disable to make it work.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
'Dim WatchRange     As Range <-- I needed to disable to make it work.

'Set WatchRange = Columns("G:G") <-- I needed to disable to make it work.
'If Not Intersect(Target, WatchRange) Is Nothing Then <-- I needed to disable to make it work.

Application.EnableEvents = False
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).row

For i = 7 To LastRow
If IsEmpty(Range("G" & i)) Or Range("G" & i).Value = "" Then
    Range("F" & i).ClearContents
End If
Next i

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

The one I proposed with the help lines:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i As Long
Application.EnableEvents = False
firstRow = 7
lastrow = Sheets("Datos del Proyecto").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
i = firstRow
Do Until i > lastrow
    If Sheets("Datos del Proyecto").Range("G" & i).Value Like "" Then
        Sheets("Datos del Proyecto").Range("F" & i).ClearContents
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```